# Como posso exibir postagens em ordem alfabética, exemplo: postagens contendo A, B, C

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
   global $wpdb;
   $first_char = 'A';
   $postids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
     SELECT      ID
     FROM        $wpdb->posts
     WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
     AND        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product'
     ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title", $first_char));

    if ($postids) {
      $args = array(
        'post__in' => $postids,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1
     );

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<p>List of Posts Titles beginning with the letter <strong>' . 
    $first_char . '<strong></p>';
    $counter = 1;
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p>
            <span><?php echo $counter++; ?></span>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </p>
```

Está exibindo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No SQL, basta alterar de `= 'A'` para `in ('A', 'B', ..., 'E')`, não?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss deu erro, consegue fazer um exemplo mais concreto ?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: No `WHERE SUBSTR()` ele tá verificando se o primeiro caractere é `A` somente. Você podia obter todos os registros do banco e lidar com a filtragem no PHP. Creio que não haverá um número supermassivo de postagens a ponto de travar o servidor.

Comment: @CypherPotato consegue me fazer um exemplo?

Comment: @Johnny remove a linha do `where` e na hora de iterar o resultado da busca, verifica se a primeira letra é `a, b`.

Comment: @CypherPotato eu fiz isto mas não deu certo, ele não exibe nada quando altero a linha do where.

Comment: Afinal vc quer simplesmente ordenar alfabéticamente ou também filtrar pela letra inicial? Como na sua página tem `List of Posts Titles beginning with the letter A`, imagino que vc queira fazer uma página para cada letra, certo? Ou serviria ter todos os posts ordenados e apresentados na mesma página? E paginação, é ou não é para ter?

Answer (score -1):

No exemplo abaixo eu ordeno uma listagem de um Custom Post Type pela data:

```
$args = array(
            'author' => $user, //exibe apenas posts criados pelo usuário 
            'post_status' => 'publish', //pega apenas posts publicados
            'post_type' => 'me_dailyrecords', //tipo do post que deve retornar
            'paged' => $paged, //respeitando a paginação                
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', //para ordenar valores numéricos
            'meta_key' => $prefix . 'date', //campo data em timestamp
            'order' => 'DESC', //ordena do maior para o menor
        );
```

E como resultado obtenho algo desse tipo:

[image: Registros ordenados pela data de maneira descendente]

Já no seu caso onde a intenção é ordenar pelo nome, você precisa trocar no parâmetro "orderby" o valor de "meta_value_num" (para ordenação de valores numéricos) para o valor "meta_value" que é o adequado para ordenação de textos..

Em "meta_key" você deverá colocar o nome do campo que deseja ordenar - que no seu caso acredito que seja o campo "title" (padrão do WordPress) onde é salvo o título do post.

Já no parâmetro "order" você deve trocar o valor do parâmetro para conseguir ordenar do menor para o maior (a,b,c), pois no bloco de código do exemplo que dei logo acima o resultado está sendo ordenando no maior para o menor (c,b,a) - para fazer essa troca basta substituir "DESC" por "ASC".

Sendo assim, seu código ficaria como algo do tipo:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $postids,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', //para ordenar valores NÃO numéricos
    'meta_key' => 'title', //campo com o nome/título do post (products)
    'order' => 'ASC', //instrução para ordenar de forma ascendente
 );
```

Perceba que adicionei apenas os 3 parâmetros que expliquei logo acima no seu array $args e com isso o resultado da ordenação agora deverá ser o que você espera.

Teste e me diga se funcionou...

Abraço!

Referência: [Documentação sobre WP_Query presente no site de desenvolvedores do WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)